# Python coverage test percentage higher than expected

Tags: python, json, pytest, coverage.py

Python 3.10

I'm working on my first Python project and am confused by the following output when I run

`coverage run -m pytest` followed by `venv/bin/coverage report --show-missing`. I'm specifically referring to the coverage percentage for `src/catday/store_data.py`.

(For context, I'm working on a game where you play as a cat.)

Output:

```
`'Name                                Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------
src/catday/__init__.py                  0      0   100%
src/catday/__main__.py                 12     12     0%   2-16
src/catday/cat_functions.py            93      2    98%   30, 120
src/catday/cat_intro.py                 6      0   100%
src/catday/cat_situations.py            8      0   100%
src/catday/player_queries.py           64     64     0%   3-86
src/catday/playthrough_intro.py        10      0   100%
src/catday/playthrough_queries.py     104    104     0%   3-132
src/catday/store_data.py               60      2    97%   38, 63
-----------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                 357    184    48%
'
```

As you can see, the coverage is showing 97%, yet I haven't written a single test for that module yet. The other coverage results aren't surprising to me; `*queries.py` haven't had tests written for them yet.

Within `/store_data.py` there are 102 lines of code, so I'll try to be as concise as possible. There are two classes - `StorePlayerData` and `StorePlaythroughData`. Each class's `__init__` does nothing more than initialize attributes for the new instance. Following that, `StorePlayerData` has two methods: one that writes player information to a `.json` file, and one that writes cat information to a `.json` file.

```
class StorePlayerData:
    def __init__(self, pthruplayer_name, pthrucat_name, pthruscore, pthrurisk, catcolor, catfriend):
        self.pthruplayer_name = pthruplayer_name
        self.pthrucat_name = pthrucat_name
        self.pthruscore = pthruscore
        self.pthrurisk = pthrurisk
        self.catcolor = catcolor
        self.catfriend = catfriend'`

`'def player_mod(self):
        players = path.parents[2] / 'game_data/players.json'
        with open(players, 'r') as file:
            jsondict = json.load(file)
            print(file.read())
            if self.pthruplayer_name not in jsondict:
                *jsondict[self.pthruplayer_name] = {
                        'risk': {
                            'possible': 36,
                            'actual': self.pthrurisk
                            },
                        'totalplaythroughs': 1,
                        'cats': {
                                self.pthrucat_name: 0,
                        },
                        }
            else:
                jsondict[self.pthruplayer_name]['totalplaythroughs'] += 1
                jsondict[self.pthruplayer_name]['risk']['possible'] += 36
                jsondict[self.pthruplayer_name]['risk']['actual'] += self.pthrurisk
        tmp_path = players.with_name(players.name + '.tmp')
        with tmp_path.open('w') as file:
            json.dump(jsondict, file)
        tmp_path.replace(players)
```

With minor differences, the `player_mod` and `cat_mod` methods are virtually identical. Note that lines 38 and 63 are shown as not having `coverage`. Line 38 has a `*` to the immediate left of it above.

The instance of said classes are created within `cat_functions.py`, which does most of the legwork for running the game itself. The main difference between the `store_data.py` module and the other modules is that the former contains code and loads then dumps information to a `.json` file.

Whether or not this is relevant, I'm wondering if it's possible to even write a test for the above methods because the methods rely on accessing and writing to a specific file; and writing a test that calls said methods could tarnish the data within the file. None of the other modules contain code for loading or dumping into a `.json` file.

I appreciate any insights you can provide. If you have further questions or need further details, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: A possibility: could coverage be showing such an (unexpectedly) high coverage rate because there isn't an sort of "state" to be tested for (i.e. nothing an `assert` can be ran against) at the conclusion of the method(s)? I don't know if that makes

Comment: Do the tested modules import and use those classes? That would cause the coverage. If so, you are already tarnishing the data. Its common to mock fake calls to functions not under test. The users of these classes could use a mock that doesn't write (and that can inject errors for test) instead of the real one. Its also common to make a root directory configurable. The unittest would use a temporary directory. This is a large topic!

Comment: @tdelaney - Yes, `cat_functions.py` uses those classes. I don't see how that's tarnishing the data if the purpose of those classes is to make modifications to the file. Regarding the tmp_dir piece, I know that pytest offers a fixture for both a temporary file and a temporary directory, but I'm not sure how I can call the `player_mod` method within the `test_store_data.py` module without also opening and writing to the `.json` file.

Comment: @tdelaney - Okay, I believe I understand now. BECAUSE the `cat_functions.py` module imports and uses those classes AND my current suite of tests executes the functions within `cat_functions.py`, then it would follow that that is how that code is being covered. Thank you.